# chart.js time series multi axis case

Tags: chart.js

Suppose several independent time series of (unixTime, value) points. For example, CarSpeed and CarRemainingFuel. I would like to create a multi axis plot (Y1 axis for CarSpeed and Y2 axis for CarRemainingFuel). The similar questions do not cover the case of "time" type of x axis.

Below is I working example of a single time series plot. It needs to be extended for a multi-axis case.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/date-fns/1.30.1/date_fns.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>


<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#myChart").width( $(window).width() *0.97 );
    $("#myChart").height( $(window).height() * 0.8 );

    var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

    const options = {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            datasets: [{
            label: 'CarSpeed',
            data: carSpeedData,
            borderColor: 'pink'
            }]
        },
        options: {
            parsing: false,
            normalized: true,
            animation: false,
            responsive: false,
            scales: {
            x: {
                type: 'time',
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Time (client time zone)',
                    font: {
                        size: 24
                    }
                }
            },
            y: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: 'Car Speed, mph',
                    font: {
                        size: 24
                    }
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }

    new Chart(ctx, options);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add an extra scale in the scale config and use the `yAxisID` in the dataset to link to it

```js
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [{
          x: new Date('09-08-2021 12:04'),
          y: 10
        }, {
          x: new Date('09-08-2021 12:08'),
          y: 15
        }, {
          x: new Date('09-08-2021 12:12'),
          y: 5
        }, {
          x: new Date('09-08-2021 12:30'),
          y: 8
        }],
        borderColor: 'pink',
        yAxisID: 'y'
      },
      {
        type: 'bar',
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [{
          x: new Date('09-08-2021 12:04'),
          y: 4
        }, {
          x: new Date('09-08-2021 12:08'),
          y: 6
        }, {
          x: new Date('09-08-2021 12:12'),
          y: 12
        }, {
          x: new Date('09-08-2021 12:30'),
          y: 18
        }, {
          x: new Date('09-08-2021 12:022'),
          y: 10
        }, {
          x: new Date('09-08-2021 12:38'),
          y: 15
        }, {
          x: new Date('09-08-2021 12:52'),
          y: 5
        }, {
          x: new Date('09-08-2021 12:59'),
          y: 8
        }],
        backgroundColor: 'orange',
        yAxisID: 'y2'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        type: 'time',
      },
      y: {
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'Car Speed, mph',
          font: {
            size: 24
          }
        }
      },
      y2: {
        position: 'right',
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: 'secondY',
          font: {
            size: 24
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```